# What is the TikZ equivalent for \psline[origin={1,2}](3;45) ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

`\psline[origin={1,2}](3;45)` draws a line `3` units long at an angle of `45 degrees` starting from the point `(1,2)`.

What is the TikZ equivalent for `\psline[origin={1,2}](3;45)` ?

Comment: Both Martin's and Andrew's solutions are accepted. But I chose Andrew for a trivial reason. :D

Comment: To try to justify the acceptance (!), I've added a reference to the relevant part of the manual (and I noticed that there are _two_ polar coordinate systems so I also added a note about that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify polar coordinates using the `(angle:radius)` syntax, so a line at an angle of 45 degree and length 3 is `(45:3)`.  But as a bare coordinate, this is centred at the origin.  So we need to shift it using either `+` or `++` (depending on whether we want to shift the point from which we compute the *next* point as well).  Thus:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw (0,0) (1,2) --  +(45:3) -- +(90:2);
\tikz \draw (0,0) (1,2) -- ++(45:3) -- +(90:2);
\end{document}
```

In both, the `(45:3)` is relative to the point `(1,2)` (as requested) but in the first the `(90:2)` is also relative to the point `(1,2)` as opposed to the second where it is relative to the point specified by `(45:3)`.

Result (sort of, see below):

[image: tikz angles]

(I hope that the circles aren't distracting.  They're there to emphasise where the specified points are.)

---

(**Added in Edit**) The details on polar coordinates is in Section 13.2.1 (*Canvas, XYZ, and Polar Coordinate Systems*) of the pgfmanual (in my version, which is PGF2.10, polar coordinates are on p125).  In looking up this reference, I noticed a subtlety about polar coordinates.  There are two versions: `canvas polar` and `xyz polar`.  In the latter, one is allowed to predefine an *x* vector and a *y* vector which will be taken as the new *x* and *y* vectors for any subsequent non-canvas coordinate calculations.  So `canvas polar` is *always* with respect to the canvas whereas `xyz polar` is with respect to the current coordinate system in use.  The subtlety is that the *implicit* form of specifying a polar coordinate, as `(angle:radius)` contains within it a way of choosing whether to be `canvas polar` or `xyz polar`.  If the `radius` contains an explicit unit then it is `canvas polar`, otherwise it is `xyz polar`.

Most of the time this will be of no concern.  In particular, if you don't mess with the *x* and *y* vectors, the two are equivalent.

(**Added in second edit**) As requested, grid lines, plus (automatic!) coordinates.  The *actual* code to produce the diagram was:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{c/.style={insert path={node[fill,circle] {} node[above left] {(\pgfmathparse{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},\pgfmathparse{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})}}}}
\tikzset{ce/.style={c,insert path=(current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east)}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[ce] (0,0)[c] (1,2)[c] --  +(45:3)[c] -- +(90:2)[ce];
\tikz \draw (0,0)[c] (1,2)[c] -- ++(45:3)[c] -- +(90:2)[ce];
\end{document}
```

(The factor `0.03514598035` is (apparently) the conversion from TeX points to cm)

Comment: It will be easier to relate coordinates in the code with the corresponding objects in the rendered diagram if you also show the navigational grids on the diagram.

Comment: @xport: As requested!

Answer (score 4):

It would be:

```
\draw (1,2) -- +(45:3);
```

It starts at (1,2). The `--` means that a line should be drawn (without only a "move" is done). The `+` means that the next coordinate is relative to the current one and `(45:3)` stands for the angle and the length.

Comment: @xport: If you want to keep drawing then you can use `++` instead of `+` to make the new point the reference for all following `+` coordinates.